# ASP.net VB going back to the previous page keeps reopening the same current page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, redirect

I have 2 asp pages, in page 1 I have a button with onclick function like this:

```
     onclick="window.location='pages/page2.aspx?code=<%=code1 %>&#39;"
```

where code1 is a parameter I'm passing

Now in page 2, I have a cancel button that is supposed to get me back to page1, i tried to do it in javascript location.href and I also tried this in the back vb code:

```
   Response.Write("../page1.aspx")
```

The problem is, when clicking the cancel code, the page1 starts loading then it automatically redirects to page 2 with the same parameter

Can you please help me out? why is this happening?

Thank you

Comment: _"i tried to do it in javascript location.href"_ Show that code and also the full aspx of that button

Comment: Why are  you using Response.Write.. You should be using Response.Redirect